# Induction on Recurrence Relations

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification, recurrence-relations

I have written the following proof, but I don't quite get to where I need to be at the end, and can't figure out where.

A sequence is defined by the recurrence relation $ U_1 = \frac{1}{2}, U_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+u_n}, n  ≥1 $

I am proving by mathematical induction this is the same as the explicit formula $ U_n = \frac{n}{n+1} $

$ P(n) : \ U_n=\frac{n}{n+1} $ for all positive integers n

Let $ n =1 $  \
$U_1=\frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2} $
This matches our given $u_1$

Asssume that when $n=k$, $u_k = \frac{k}{k+1}$

Let $n=k+1 =>$ need to show that $U_{k+1} = \frac{k+1}{k+1+1} $

\begin{align}
       \ U_{k+1} &= \frac{\ U_k}{u_k+1} \\\\
     \ &= \frac{\frac{k}{k+1}}{\frac{k}{k+1}+1} \\\\
     \ &= \frac{k}{2k+1}
     \end{align}

And that last line is where I go wrong. The steps I've taken seem good to me, and this is where I was expecting to simplify out to get my previous $U_{k+1}$, but evidently not. Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you have made here is with your substitution into $U_{k+1}$. Recall that our recurrence relation is defined as $U_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+U_n}$. As such, we only substitute our inductive hypothesis into the denominator, whereas you have substituted it into both the numerator and the denominator. So, doing the correct substitution will lead to the expression $$ U_{k+1} = \frac{k}{ k + \frac{k}{k+1} }. $$ Then, proceeding with some algebra will lead you to what is required.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \ U_{k+1} &= \frac{\ k}{k+u_k} \\\\
     \ &= \frac{k}{k+\frac{k}{k+1}} \\\\
     \ &= \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}